# Argument name in function prototype

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

AS in function decleration, three things are required i.e.
Return value type. Function name.  (argument type).
but argument name is not necessary. Then why this program generates an error, when i remove the argument name ( `arr[][maxCols]` ) from the function prototype (`void readMatrix(int arr[][maxCols] );`)

In simple words.

```
void readMatrix(int arr[][maxCols] );    // fine and no error.

void readMatrix(int);                    // but this generates error when argument name is not mentioned in function prototype.
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: You got rid of more than just the name.

Comment: 16 13 D:\DATADATA\myprogs2\Untitled1.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'int (*)[3]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Comment: 10 6 D:\DATADATA\myprogs2\Untitled1.cpp [Error] initializing argument 1 of 'void readMatrix(int)' [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 7):

Because `[][maxCols]` does not belong to the name but to the type.

For a declaration without a name, write:

```
void f(int [][maxCols])
```

And raw arrays are usually a poor choice. Use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: std::vector? what ifhe is using c?

Comment: You are right, I missed the C tag. But I have the strong feeling that the author simply doesn't know that those are two different languages.